# Intellij Idea: Highlight usage of element at caret option. Change color

Tags: ide, intellij-idea

I just turned on "Highlight usage of element at caret".  (Settings -> editor).  But the default color is a light blue.  I would really like this highlighting to bolder and easier to see.  I could not find an option in the colors menu.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Yup.
Settings > Editor  > Colors & Fonts > General > Identifier under caret

Comment: And "Identifier under caret (write)"

Comment: In IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2 it's under Settings > Editor > Color Scheme > General > Code > Identifier under caret

Comment: Yup, and I was sure it wasn't working. It was black on black, changed it to shiny red. And `Highlight usages of element at caret` was on but I thought it wasn't working.

Answer (score 3):

Go to,  File -> power save mode

Disable the power save mode and syntax highlighting will start working again.

syntax highlighting is a background processes in intellij which does not execute in power save mode